# Generate report by date time with ReportNG after each test finished

Tags: html, reportng

I use Selenium webdriver, testng and reportng to develop automation test framework, everything works fine, reportNG gernates html report after each test finished, but the html report will be overritten by the next round test;

so, i'm considering if any parameters that can be configured in Reportng to keep HTML report will not be overwritten, just create and save by date and time separately; could you please tell me where to do the settings in reportng? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem, just decompile the reportng jar file, then modified source code, and pack the jar with modified code.